# MongoDB return a result as of [object Object]

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a multi layers schema:

```
{
  a:String,
  aList: 
  [
     {
        b:String,
        bList:
        [
            {
                c:String,
                cList 
                [
                   d1:String
                   d2:String   
                ]
            }  
        ] 
     }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that when I retrieve as followedin

```
A.find( {a:aid, "aList.b":bid}, {_id:0, "aList.$.bList" : 1})
```

The bList is always returned as a list of Strings and I can't get the original data

```
{
  aList:
  [
     {
        bList: [ "[object Object]", "[object Object]", "[object Object]"] 
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you printing out the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the schema as follow solved the problem:

```
var cSchema = mongoose.Schema({c:String,
    cList[
       d1:String
       d2:String   
    ]
});

var bSchema = mongoose.Schema({c:String,
    b:String,
    bList:
    [cSchema]
});


var aSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    a:String,
    aList: [bSchema]
});
```